# Basic loop and if statement issue in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

So I have an angular function that aims to grab some basic details from an array of objects, by looking up using an id, passed into the function.

Anyway, the function works - the first time. That is, it successfully returns the customer name of the first object where the contract id's match. However, if there is more than one contract/object that matches, it only returns the first name.

I understand this must be a basic problem with regards to looping, but can't seem to get it to work!

Thanks so much in advance.

Here is the function:

```
$scope.getCompanyDetailsByContractId = function(contractId) {

    for (var i = $scope.customers.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

        if ($scope.customers[i].contracts[i].id == contractId ) {
            return $scope.customers[i].name;
        };

    };;

}
```

And here is the data structures:

```
$scope.customers = [{
            id: 1,
            name: "John Inc",
            currentContractLength: 12,
            currentContractValue: 18000,
            startDate: "09/01/2014",
            endDate: "09/01/2015",
            nextRenewalDate: "09/01/2015",
            mrr: 1500,
            contracts: [{
                id: 234,
                status: "won",
                contractNumber: 1,
                value: 18000,
                startDate: "09/01/2014",
                endDate: "09/01/2015",
                nextRenewalDate: "09/01/2014"
            },
            {
                id: 235,
                status: "pending",
                contractNumber: 2,
                value: 18000,
                startDate: "09/01/2015",
                endDate: "09/01/2016",
                nextRenewalDate: "09/01/2016"
            }]

        }, {
            id: 2,
            name: "Peters Company Ltd",
            currentContractLength: 3,
            currentContractValue: 15000,
            startDate: "09/01/2014",
            endDate: "09/01/2015",
            nextRenewalDate: "09/01/2015",
            mrr: 1500,
            contracts: [{
                id: 543654,
                status: "won",
                contractNumber: 1,
                value: 4200,
                startDate: "09/01/2014",
                endDate: "09/01/2015",
                nextRenewalDate: "09/01/2014"
            },
            {
                id: 54354,
                status: "pending",
                contractNumber: 2,
                value: 18000,
                startDate: "09/01/2015",
                endDate: "09/01/2016",
                nextRenewalDate: "09/01/2016"
            }]
        }];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you should do 2 loops to look in all possibles contracts.

With the following call you are looking only for the contract with index `i`

```
$scope.customers[i].contracts[i].id == contractId
```

Maybe you should do something like

```
for (var i = $scope.customers.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

    for (var j = 0; j < $scope.customers[i].contracts.length; j++) {
        if ($scope.customers[i].contracts[j].id == contractId ) {
            return $scope.customers[i].name;
        };
    }


};
```